# How to make Serial BCD code input in verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm making a Verilog Code for a simple up&down game.
For this, I have to make a 4 digit Decimal number for input.

```
module Updown(
    Reset, Clk,
    SEG_COM, SEG_DATA, // 4 digit binary number
    a,b,c,d,e,f,g, // u, d, O
    bta, btb, btc, btd, bte, btf, btg, bth, bti, btj
    );
     input Reset, Clk;
     input bta, btb, btc, btd, bte, btf, btg, bth, bti, btj;

     output a,b,c,d,e,f,g;
     output reg [3:0] SEG_COM;
     output reg [7:0] SEG_DATA;


     integer CNT_SCAN;
     integer CNT;

     reg [3:0] Num_in;
     reg [15:0] Num;
     reg bta1, btb1, btc1, btd1, bte1, btf1, btg1, bth1, bti1, btj1; // one shot control
     wire bt1, bt2, bt3, bt4, bt5, bt6, bt7, bt8, bt9, bt0;

     always @(posedge Clk or negedge Reset)
     begin
      if (~Reset)
      begin
      bta1 = 0;
      btb1 = 0;
      btc1 = 0;
      btd1 = 0;
      bte1 = 0;
      btf1 = 0;
      btg1 = 0;
      bth1 = 0;
      bti1 = 0;
      btj1 = 0;
      end
      else
       begin
        bta1 = bta;
       btb1 = btb;
       btc1 = btc;
       btd1 = btd;
       bte1 = bte;
       btf1 = btf;
       btg1 = btg;
       bth1 = bth;
       bti1 = bti;
       btj1 = btj;
        end
     end

     assign bt1 = bta & ~bta1;
     assign bt2 = btb & ~btb1;
     assign bt3 = btc & ~btc1;
     assign bt4 = btd & ~btd1;
     assign bt5 = bte & ~bte1;
     assign bt6 = btf & ~btf1;
     assign bt7 = btg & ~btg1;
     assign bt8 = bth & ~bth1;
     assign bt9 = bti & ~bti1;
     assign bt0 = btj & ~btj1;

     always @(posedge Clk)
     begin
     if (bt1)
     Num_in = 1;
     else if (bt2)
     Num_in = 2;
     else if (bt3)
     Num_in = 3;
     else if (bt4)
     Num_in = 4;
     else if (bt5)
     Num_in = 5;
     else if (bt6)
     Num_in = 6;
     else if (bt7)
     Num_in = 7;
     else if (bt8)
     Num_in = 8;
     else if (bt9)
     Num_in = 9;
     else if (bt0)
     Num_in = 0;
     end


     always @(posedge Clk or negedge Reset)
     begin
     if (~Reset)
     Num = 4'b0000;
     else
     begin
      Num[3:0] = Num[7:4];
      Num[7:4] = Num[11:8];
      Num[11:8] = Num[15:12];
      Num[15:12] = Num_in [3:0];
     end
     end

     always @(posedge Clk or negedge Reset)
     begin
     if (~Reset)
     CNT_SCAN = 0;
     else
      begin
      if (CNT_SCAN >=3)
      CNT_SCAN = 0;
      else
      CNT_SCAN = CNT_SCAN + 1;
      end
     end

     always @(posedge Clk or negedge Reset)
     begin
     if (~Reset)
     begin
     SEG_COM = 4'hF;
     SEG_DATA = 8'h00;
     end
     else
      begin
      case (CNT_SCAN)
      0 : begin
      SEG_COM = 4'h7;
      case (Num[3:0])
      0 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11111100;
      1 : SEG_DATA = 8'b01100000;
      2 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11011010;
      3 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11110010;
      4 : SEG_DATA = 8'b01100110;
      5 : SEG_DATA = 8'b10110110;
      6 : SEG_DATA = 8'b10111110;
      7 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11100100;
      8 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11111110;
      9 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11110110;
      default : SEG_DATA = 8'h00;
      endcase
      end
      1 : begin
      SEG_COM = 8'hB;
      case (Num[7:4])
      0 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11111100;
      1 : SEG_DATA = 8'b01100000;
      2 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11011010;
      3 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11110010;
      4 : SEG_DATA = 8'b01100110;
      5 : SEG_DATA = 8'b10110110;
      6 : SEG_DATA = 8'b10111110;
      7 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11100100;
      8 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11111110;
      9 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11110110;
      default : SEG_DATA = 8'h00;
      endcase
      end
      2 : begin
      SEG_COM = 8'hD;
      case (Num[11:8])
      0 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11111100;
      1 : SEG_DATA = 8'b01100000;
      2 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11011010;
      3 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11110010;
      4 : SEG_DATA = 8'b01100110;
      5 : SEG_DATA = 8'b10110110;
      6 : SEG_DATA = 8'b10111110;
      7 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11100100;
      8 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11111110;
      9 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11110110;
      default : SEG_DATA = 8'h00;
      endcase
      end
      3 : begin
      SEG_COM = 8'hE;
      case (Num[15:12])
      0 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11111100;
      1 : SEG_DATA = 8'b01100000;
      2 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11011010;
      3 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11110010;
      4 : SEG_DATA = 8'b01100110;
      5 : SEG_DATA = 8'b10110110;
      6 : SEG_DATA = 8'b10111110;
      7 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11100100;
      8 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11111110;
      9 : SEG_DATA = 8'b11110110;
      default : SEG_DATA = 8'h00;
      endcase
      end
      default : begin
      SEG_COM = 8'hFF;
      SEG_DATA = 8'h00;
      end
      endcase
      end
      end



endmodule
```

This is not a final version, just making now.
The problem is all the numbers are same when I press one button.
I want to make it as serial inputs, like when i press 9321 then the 7 Segment display should show 9321 but now it is working like 9999, 3333, 2222, 1111.
I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the clock is running so fast that when you hold down a particular button it updates the least-significant digit in cycle 0, followed by the next in cycle 1, etc, etc, so fast that they all end up with the same value.  You'll need to add logic to only update a single digit when "a button is pressed in this cycle but was not pressed in the previous cycle".

Comment: Don't forget to debounce the "pressed" signal as well, in case the button isn't hardware debounced.

Answer (score 0):

`Num_in` is only updated on a button press. But `Num` is contently down-shifting and concatenating itself with `Num_in`. `Num` should only be updated once per press as well. You could add a flop to assert one cycle after a button press, or you could remove the need for `Num_in`:

```
always @(posedge Clk or negedge Reset)
begin
  if (~Reset)
    Num <= 4'b0000;
  else if (bt1)
    Num[15:0] <= {4'd1, Num[15:4]};
  else if (bt2)
    Num[15:0] <= {4'd2, Num[15:4]};
  else if (bt3)
    Num[15:0] <= {4'd3, Num[15:4]};
  else if (bt4)
    Num[15:0] <= {4'd4, Num[15:4]};
  else if (bt5)
    Num[15:0] <= {4'd5, Num[15:4]};
  else if (bt6)
    Num[15:0] <= {4'd6, Num[15:4]};
  else if (bt7)
    Num[15:0] <= {4'd7, Num[15:4]};
  else if (bt8)
    Num[15:0] <= {4'd8, Num[15:4]};
  else if (bt9)
    Num[15:0] <= {4'd9, Num[15:4]};
  else if (bt0)
    Num[15:0] <= {4'd0, Num[15:4]};
end
```

FYI, synchronous logic should be assigned with non-blocking assignment (`<=`). Doing so will prevent a potential race conditions in the verilog scheduler during simulation (synthesis doesn't care but may give warnings).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I'll go my lab tomorrow and check it out, hope it will works!